# Computer randomly loses signal to monitor

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

Around a month ago I build my first computer, and I've had no problems until now. For about a week my computer has lost signal to the monitor, is only able to be turned off from the PSU. (The fans still run but front panel power doesn't work) I'm wondering what the problem could be.

At first I suspected that it was a GPU issue, but now I'm not so sure. The computer will work for several hours and then will begin do this randomly.

I'm also planning on upgrading my PSU and getting a new CPU heatsink soon, would this have an affect on the performance?

---

What I've tried:

- MSI Afterburner > Set constant voltage
- Set monitor settings to never turn off
- Monitoring GPU temps
- updating all drivers

---

Build:

- Intel Pentium G3258
- MSI Radeon R7 250X
- MSI H81M-E34
- 8GB Crucial Ballistix Sport
- 1TB Western Digital Blue
- 430W Corsair CX430
- Fractal Design Core 1100